# Save Devextreme Pivot grid to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress, devextreme, devexpress-mvc

I am using Devextreme js components. I am loading data to Devextreme PivotGrid component and I want to save PivotGrid to my database. I saw **PivotGridSettings** in Devexpress. I wonder that may I use that class in my MVC project.
By the way I storaged PivotGrid to browser local storage. I wonder any way except of using Local storage?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show any code to implement `PivotGridSettings` in your site? I think you can store PivotGrid contents in DB, but hard to tell anything without example provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PivotGrid provides the stateStoring option. It helps you store the PivotGrid's settings.

For example, when this option is enabled, PivotGrid stores its settings in a browser's local storage. 

If you want to store them in your database, use the `custom` type of storage. Just define actions on saving and loading a state via specifying the `customSave` and `customLoad` callback functions. Send the JSON state to your database on `customSave` and then apply it to the PivotGrid back on `customLoad`.

You can find more information about the stateStoring feature in the [DevExtreme documentation](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxPivotGrid/Configuration/stateStoring/).

By the way, this is [Demo](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/PivotGrid/StatePersistence/jQuery/Light/) where you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't save the calculated data from a PivotGrid because it reads data from a data source you provide, the calculations done by the PivotGrid depend on the data source.